# Tor Browser is updated even when it is not open?

Tags: vpn

Good morning everyone and thank you in advance for your answers :). I use VPN on my computer and I also downloaded the Tor Browser. When I turn on the computer, I connect to the Internet and turn my VPN and only after I turn Tor Browser so my ISP knows only that I connect to my VPN and my VPN knows only that I connect to the Tor Browser. Even when I want to disconnect myself, I close Tor Browser and after I disconnect from the VPN, and finally I get disconnected from the internet. Now, I have enabled automatic updates in the Tor Browser (it says that it is safer to have them), and my question is: Can Tor Browser update even when it is not open? I'm not always connected to the VPN, when I browse with the normal browser, and I do not want my ISP knows that I use Tor Browser (in fact if it would update also when it is not opened, it could be updated even when I'm not connected to the VPN.) thank you in advance for your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Automatic updates are only done while Tor Browser is running. Just make sure it is not running while your VPN is off.